# Azure ML Web Service Parmeters Input

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Looking to use Azure ML to allow the input value to be inputted through the web service call.  As of now, I have the datasource and and SQL Transformation.

[image]

[image]

In the SQL transformation, here is my code that does not accept the parmeter:

```
select pagename, cp 
from t1
where %webserviceparm
```